# Revert a single change in a file in Git

Tags: git

**EDIT:** As was pointed out in comments, this operation is not actually a "revert". A more appropriate description would be to *"Interactively select hunks in the difference between the  (or the index, if unspecified) and the working tree."*

How do I revert a single block of changes in Git? For instance in the example below, from 'git diff' for only one file, I want to revert the second block (@@ -441,7 +442,7 @@), but not the first one (@@ -383,7 +384,7 @@).
The example is just that, an example. The real case is if I have big and several blocks of changes, not just one line. This is just for illustration purposes.

```
@@ -383,7 +384,7 @@
 (...)
-foo foo foo
-fooza fooza fooza 
+bar bar bar
+barza barza barza 
 (...)

@@ -441,7 +442,7 @@
 (...)
-rpc_address: localhost
+rpc_address: "127.0.0.2"
 (...)
```

Comment: Why don't you just... make that change? What's the outcome you're hoping for, exactly?

Comment: This is just an example, the real case is if I have big and several blocks of changes, not just one line. This is just for illustration purposes.

Comment: Note that revert has a specific meaning in git (see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert), which it seems like doesn't actually apply to you.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for pointing that out. I was unaware of that meaning in Git. I come from an SVN background where revert has the functionality I was looking for here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, if the file is staged, you can't do much. If it's the case, unstage it with:

```
git reset HEAD <file>
```

Now we're in a state where we can selectively revert/stage *patches* of our file:

To revert only some chunks (these chunks **will be lost forever!**):

```
git checkout -p <file>
```

To stage only some chunks:

```
git add -p <file>
```

In the removal/addition dialog that follows, the most useful options are `s` (which allows you to further *split* a chunk), `y` (yes) or `n` (no).